# Unusual proof that $M$ is Noetherian if and only if $N$ and $M/N$ are Noetherian

Tags: commutative-algebra, modules, noetherian

Let $M$ be an $R$-module for a ring $R$. Let $N$ be a submodule of $M$. I read that one can prove that $M$ is Noetherian if and only if $N$ and $M/N$ are Noetherian using these two results:

1) If $M$ is finitely generated and $A$ is a submodule, then $M/A$ is finitely generated.

2) If, for a submodule $A$, $A$ and $M/A$ are finitely generated, then $M$ is finitely generated.

I see how to prove the original result based on ascending chains but not how to do it using these results... Could someone enlight me here? It would be very helpful as I'm getting confused.

Comment: Hint: select generators of $A$ and $M/A$ and lift to find generators for $M$.

Comment: Thank you! That is to prove (2), right? I think I have that right!

Comment: Related: http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1645230/if-m-n-and-n-are-noetherian-r-modules-then-so-is-m

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Let's prove that, if $N$ and $M/N$ are noetherian, then $M$ is noetherian. We need to see that every submodule of $M$ is finitely generated.

Consider a submodule $L$ of $M$. Then $L\cap N$ is a submodule of $N$, hence finitely generated. Also $(L+N)/N$, as a submodule of $M/N$ is finitely generated. Consider the exact sequence
$$
0\to L\cap N\to L\to L/(L\cap N)\to 0
$$
Since
$$
L/(L\cap N)\cong (L+N)/N
$$
is finitely generated, also $L$ is finitely generated because of fact 2.

For the converse, assume $M$ is noetherian and that $N$ is a submodule of $M$. Then $N$ is noetherian, because every submodule of $N$ is also a submodule of $M$. For $M/N$ recall that a submodule of $M/N$ is of the form $L/N$, where $L$ is a submodule of $M$ and $N\subseteq L$. Then $L/N$ is finitely generated because of fact 1.

Comment: That is genius! Thank you!! Does the other way around look similar? If $M$ is Noetherian then $N$ clearly is so too. As for $M/N$, it is finitely generated since $M$ is... but that's not enough...

Comment: @Kika Assume $M$ is noetherian. For $N$ noetherian there's no problem, because every submodule of $N$ is a submodule of $M$. For $M/N$, just recall that every submodule of $M/N$ has the form $L/N$, where $L$ is a submodule of $M$ and $N\subseteq L$. Since $L$ is finitely generated, also $L/N$ is.

Comment: Right! I wasn't sure that I could give this form to any submodule of $M/N$! Thanks!

Comment: @egreg What's the importance to consider the exact sequence ? Since we can write $L/(L\cap N)\cong (L+N)/N$ from 2nd Isomorphism theorem.

Comment: @S717717 That's essentially for having a better look of the situation.